# Showing users alternative payment methods.

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Im building an app with in app payments. My user base is likely to use bitcoin so my question is, am I allowed to add a bitcoin payment additionally to the normal in app method from apple ?

I know about 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

But im not sure if this means that im only allowed to use their system or if I could add other methods if the user doesnt want to use theirs.

Does anybody have experience with this or already asked Apple about this ? I would also like to hear about how Google is handling this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use something else than IAP to buy **digital** products.
For **non-digital** products you must not use IAP.

Nicolas